# Rules for non-players distracting players in a hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, etiquette

Are there rules about people who are loud and talking over players heads distracting those who are in game?

I was in a hand, a person not in the game was standing behind me talking to a player across the table from us loudly over my head. I found it very distracting to my game... I asked him to tone it down because I was in a hand and he was distracting me  and he said he didn't need to.

Is there a poker rule about this kind of distraction while a game is in play?

Comment: Where was this? A casino, a home game, or someplace else?

Comment: If that person isn't on the table I don't think there is much that can be done if it's a public card room/casino. If the person was at the table and talking during a hand, there is absolutely rules in play for this.

Comment: this is not a poker rule, but a general house rule. You can easily adress this to the dealer and he will take care. He should take care of the happiness of the casinos / houses clients.

Comment: I wish you would post valid comments as answers.  I would up vote.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback, the game is in a local league i belong to, love the league and people...looks like the answer is really in the house rules, i did talk to the person running it afterwords, he did agree that he misunderstood what happened and the person should use common courtesy to other players still in game. My mistake was not calling him to the table to address the issue at that moment 
This incident left me questioning if it is part of game rules, i dont think this would be tolerated in a professional space such as a casino

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such poker rule in gerneral.
Player behaviour is often covered in the so called house rules.
Some rules which are can be found in the house rules:

- railbirds (watchers) have to keep silent when a game is running
- you are only allowed to talk about a hand when you are in a hand OR
- the current hand is not allowed to discuss on the table

If you feel disturbed by a person, playing or non playing, you can adress this to the dealer. He will surely take care, since you are the customer.

In your specific case the dealer could or should have as well noticed that you felt distracted and jump in. It's his responsibility to keep to game up and running. This also includes to remind non players to keep silence around the table.

Of course there are edge cases, if someone who is in the hand is talking a lot and it disturbes you. He is allowed to talk in general...

I always read house rules and see the tiny differencens since I use to deal as well and like to keep myself informed